# How to add a new selected option to react multiselect?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using an isMulti react-multiselect, and..
I need to add an external option to the seletedOptions but, not when I clic over the menu options (this option is outside the options passed to the select)
I want added  when  I handle a different event in another component out of

Can I do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're asking. It sounds like

- You have a list of `options`
- You already have a `value` (in this case, an array)
- You want to externally add another `option` and have it added to your `value`

Since you control the state of both `options` and `value` then this is fairly simple. First, insert your new option in your `options` array. Then push the new value into your `value` array. Something like:

```js
setOptions(prev => [...prev, {value: 6, label: 'Foo'}]);
setValue(prev => [...prev, 6]);
```

This assumes the default `getOptionLabel` and `getOptionValue`. If your option keys are different then make the proper adjustments.